# Category based content filtering for main and remote sites

Tags: domain-name-system, content-filter

**Problem:** I have one main location and about 5 remote sites. The remote sites use the DNS at the main location but have their own internet connection. I would like to implement something at the main location that blocks a slew of web sites based on different categories.

The only option I can think of is using openDNS but I think the cost might be a little high.

Is there anything that I can implement that would either be free, a one time charge, or lower cost then openDNS?

I do have a ASA5505 at each remote site, not sure if that could be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much OpenDNS costs, but [ScrubIT](http://www.scrubit.com/) does automatic filtering, with a beta program to control individual sites as well. It's also free. Maybe it'll fit your needs? It looks like [Norton also offers a DNS service](https://dns.norton.com/dnsweb/homePage.do) as well.

Lastly, you could always install your own [DNS redirector](http://dnsredirector.com/compare/).

Answer (score 1):

An ASA can integrate with a Websense or McAfee SmartFilter box via what is essentially a proprietary protocol for checking whether a URL is allowed (see [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a008088517b.shtml)).  This would allow the remote sites' ASAs to check in with a central filter for browsing permission - but the cost for one of those solutions would likely be a lot higher than OpenDNS.

I don't know of any options other than OpenDNS for purely DNS-based filtering (can you make users proxy to a central system?  or deploy a proxy at each site?) - but make sure you keep the limits of DNS filtering in mind, since it's pretty easily bypassed.

Comment: For this client a full content filtering solution is too expensive so a DNS one will work fine for %99 of the users. The main location doesn't have the bandwidth to handle all remote sites directing web traffic through it either. As it seems, openDNS is the only options for the cost here?

Comment: Yeah, unless one of the solutions that the ASA integrates with is in your cost ballpark - I don't really have a good idea of what their prices look like these days, since I haven't dealt with any web filtering in a couple years now.

Comment: I'll have to call up their sales number. No one ever list prices :(